# Use window.location in If condition to toggle between CSS files

Tags: javascript, css, spring, window.location

I'm using the below code to load a css file based on the **window.location** element.

```
<core:if test="${window.location.hostname == 'localhost'}">
<link href="././css/imageload.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</core:if>
```

The test always returns false eventhough the window.location.hostname is 'localhost'. This I have tested using an alert box.

Am I doing something wrong here? Or is there any other way to compare the window.location.hostname element?

(I'm using Spring framework. Front end is Javascript+CSS )

Comment: Does this code run in javascript or in Java?

Comment: @Chillax not sure why you're @-ing me :s

Comment: @andreas Im sorry. Corrected!

Comment: @Chillax Most probably you're wrong. Unless you're using some js templating system, which looks very like to Spring one.

Answer (score 0):

without knowing spring. the core:if is a tag it seems part of spring and the condition is js. is the use together possible? otherwise you could use only js to insert the link tag. then the logic will be called during displaying the page in a webbrowser.

```
<script>
  if( window.location.hostname == 'localhost' ) {
    document.write( "<link href='...' />" );
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Core:if is not a javascript keyword and is executed server side.

You need something that is executed client side. You also need to dynamically load the css file. You may look in dynamic loading libs like require.js for example.

Answer (score 0):

A more faster way :

```
<%@ taglib prefix="core" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

<core:set var="hostName"><%=request.getServerName()%></core:set>
<core:if test='${hostName == "localhost"}'>
    <link href="././css/imageload.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</core:if>
```